# If you apply a linear function to a span, does it result in the span of the function values of the basis vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let us assume we have a vector space V in some ring K, $f \in L(V,V)$ and a number of vectors $v_0, v_1, ..., v_n \in V$.
Does the following statement hold true?

$f(span \{v_0, v_1, ..., v_n\}) = span \{f(v_0), f(v_1), ..., f(v_n)\}$

Comment: what dou you think? What have you tried?

Comment: In particular, $K$ must be a field; otherwise, what you are describing is just a $K$-module and not a vector space.

Comment: The title of this post could be more precise: the vectors $v_0, \dots, v_n$ in the problem statement need not be linearly independent, and thus might fail to form a basis of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in \text{Span}\{v_0,v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ then $x=\alpha_1v_1+ \ldots+\alpha_nv_n$. But bu linearity of $f$, $f(x) = f(\alpha_1v_1+ \ldots+\alpha_nv_n) = \alpha_1f(v_1)+ \ldots+\alpha_nf(v_n)$, then is true that $f(\text{Span}\{v_0,v_1, \ldots, v_n\} ) \subset \text{Span}\{f(v_1), \ldots, f(v_n)\}$. The opposite inclusion follows in an analogous way by writing the elements of $\text{Span}\{f(v_1), \ldots, f(v_n)\}$  as linear combination of $f(v_1), \ldots, f(v_n)$ and using linearity

Comment: The opposite inclusion *is* always true. Your purported counterexample is not correct because indeed $\text{span}\{f(1,0),f(0,1)\} = \text{span}\{(1,1),(0,0)\} = \text{span}\{(1,1)\} = f(\mathbb{R}^2) = f(\text{span}\{(1,0), (0,1)\})$.

Comment: I edited the answer, it was a slip